# how to draw the number line of the Gregorian calendar? or is this about array indices?

Tags: arrays, calendar

I'm a self-taught programmer currently teaching some kids how to program conversions between the Hebrew and Gregorian calendars. I've got a basic confusion about the lack of a year zero on the historical (Gregorian and Julian) calendars and I seem to be too dense to understand the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero.

Here's how I understand a regular number line:

```
   -2     -1      0      1      2       integer number line
----|------|------|------|------|----
<=-2|<===-1|<===-0|0====>|1====>|2==>   item labels
3rd |  2nd |  1st | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd   ordinal numbers
```

There's one zero, and then positive and negative instances of all the other integers. The item between 0 and +1 is labeled '0' (as an array index or, for instance as an age—a baby isn't 1 year old until its second year.)

But historical calendars don't have a year zero so a regular number line doesn't work, but the labels and ordinal numbers line up:

```
    ?      ?      ?      ?      ?
----|------|------|------|------|----
<=-3|<===-2|<===-1|1====>|2====>|3==>
3rd |  2nd |  1st | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd
```

As per the article (if I'm following it correctly), astronomical calendars add a year zero before 1 AD/CE:

```
    ?      ?      ?      ?      ?
----|------|------|------|------|----
<=-2|<===-1|<====0|1====>|2====>|3==>
3rd |  2nd |  1st | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd
```

What I'm confused about is how to assign number line symbols or array indices for either historical or astronomical calendars.

On a regular number line, the interval between -1 and 0 has a label of -0 (in the one's place), and it contains numbers like -0.1 and -0.2. But arrays don't usually have negative indices since it's hard to distinguish between +0 and -0.

—Ok, now that I've explained this far, I think I can answer my own question, which I will do below. But if someone else gives a clearer or better answer, I'm happy to select it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually ok to give array negative indices. The number line looks like this:

```
   -2     -1      0      1      2       integers
----|------|------|------|------|----
<=-3|<===-2|<===-1|0====>|1====>|2==>   array indices
3rd |  2nd |  1st | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd
```

The range between -1 and 0 is labeled -1 because it *starts* with -1, so the lack of symmetry around 0 for these is fine, and on the negative side, labels match ordinal numbers even though they don't on the positive side.

The thing that was throwing me off was that the astronomical calendar shifts the labels left one unit.

Since the traditional number line is symmetrical in all three, point labels, interval labels, and ordinal labels, I thought that the astronomical calendar would have to add a year zero on both sides of the origin, even though historical calendars only get rid of a single year zero.

Whether this lengthy exercise helps anyone, it did help me. Thanks, StackOverflow!

In meeting with the kids we also figured out that arrows pointing in two directions away from the origin is appropriate for number lines and is good for symmetry around the origin. But array listings and calendar time are appropriately represented as proceeding from left to right, which makes symmetry impossible even if there is a zero point with negative numbers to the left. So, here are the various labelings with more sensible arrows:

```
   -2     -1      0      1      2       integers
----|------|------|------|------|----
    |      |      | 1st  | 2nd  | 3rd   ordinal labels
<=-2|<===-1|<===-0|0====>|1====>|2==>   real number interval labels
-3=>|-2===>|-1===>|0====>|1====>|2==>   array indices
-3=>|-2===>|-1===>|1====>|2====>|3==>   historical calendar years
-2=>|-1===>|0====>|1====>|2====>|3==>   astronomical calendar years
```